# Audio stream reconnect in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, icecast

I am using the following code in a swf created with Flash CS6:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
var customClient:Object = new Object();
ns.client = customClient;
ns.play("http://streamserver3.us:7018/stream?type=.flv");
```

It plays an Icecast audio streaming.
How could I do to reconnect automatically (if the internet connection drops, etc.)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if any of these [**`NetStreamInfo`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStreamInfo.html) options can help you detect a connection drop:

Try using a timer that fires every **two** seconds where the responding function checks if there has been a change (ie: amount of *incoming* data has become zero).

Maybe check with `ns.info.dataBytesPerSecond` but explore the descriptions of other methods in that linked Info Class. Use an `If` statement to check input has not become zero or `Else` (if now zero) run your function that reconnects (does usual `ns.stop();` & `ns.play( url );` etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. I have found a solution that works and I would like to share:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
var customClient:Object = new Object();
ns.client = customClient;
ns.play("http://xxxxxxxxx/stream?type=.flv");

ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
switch (event.info.code)
{
case 'NetStream.Play.Stop' :
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
break;
case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" :
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
break;
}
}
```

I have created a new scene "Scene 2" with the following code:

```
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");
```

Now if the stream (internet or server connection) is lost, the player will reconnect automatically to the stream.

Working great!

Thank you very much for your ideas!

Regards